# Loading an image from a website

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Im trying to create a simple app that will display an image that is posted daily. However the name of the image changes each day.

Here is what I have so far.

```
--- .h file

{ UIWebView *webView; }

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end

--- .m file

@implementation AWCViewController

@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url/images/image1.png"]];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request]; 
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. 
}

@end
```

Comment: So, what the question?

Comment: Question is how do i get the app to update the image name as it changes everyday. For example. Today the image name would be 223, tomorrow it will be 224, the next 225.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of @"url/images/image1.png"

Do

NSString *image = "image1";  // you can pass this into the method as whatever name you want

[NSString StringWithFormat:(@"url/images/%@.png",image)];

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices.

1. On every iOS device generate a different URL each day.  Use `NSString` or `NSURL` functions to change the URL; you'll need something like an `imageOfTheDayName` method to return the NSString for each day
2. Change the image on the web server every day.  On the iOS device set the image URL to `url/images/imageOfTheDay.png`.

I suggest case #2 but either can work.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this and everything depends on how you want to manage your online images.

1. You can simply leave the code that way and replace "image1.png" on your server with a different file named "image1.png" too.
2. You can set the NSURL address to something like "url/lastImage" and redirect the page to your daily image url.
3. You can create a small function both client and server that returns the name of your daily image, something like this:

   ```
   - (NSString *)dailyImageName 
   {  
       NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
      [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];    
      return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
   }
   ```

So then you know that your image filename needs to be yearmonthday.png (ex. "20130413.png")

Comment: The daily image url will change daily.